# Where can Laravel route middleware be used besides routes configuration?

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-8, middleware, laravel-middleware

I was cleaning my `Kernel.php` from unused route middleware when I noticed [the following declaration](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Kernel.php#L60):

```
'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
```

I double-checked `Kernel.php` and all the routes: the `can` middleware was not used *anywhere*. So I decided to delete it. But the next moment my test suite failed with the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Target class [can] does not exist.",                                                                                             
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException",                                                                 
    "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",                                                              
    "line": 875,                                                                                                                                 
    "trace": [                                                                                                                                   
        {                                                                                                                                        
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",                                                      
            "line": 754,                                                                                                                         
            "function": "build",                                                                                                                 
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",                                                                                         
            "type": "->"                                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                        
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",                                                   
            "line": 841,                                                                                                                         
            "function": "resolve",                                                                                                               
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",                                                                                         
            "type": "->"                                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                        
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",                                                      
            "line": 692,                                                                                                                         
            "function": "resolve",                                                                                                               
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",                                                                                      
            "type": "->"                                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                        
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",                                                   
            "line": 826,                                                                                                                         
            "function": "make",                                                                                                                  
            "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",                                                                                         
            "type": "->"                                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                        
            "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",                                                        
            "line": 156,                                                                                                                         
            "function": "make",                                                                                                                  
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",                                                                                      
            "type": "->"                                                                                                                         
        },                                                                                                                                       
        ...
```

I wasn't able to debug this yet, but it looks like *something* is trying to construct the `can` via the service container.

So the question is: where else can the `$routeMiddleware` declarations be used besides the application routing? How do you know if a given route middleware is used or not by the framework?

I think it may be related to `$user->can()` calls but I don't get it what does it have to do with *named middleware declarations*.

Answer (score 1):

The User Model by default extends the Authenticatable user model class which implements the:
AuthenticatableContract,
AuthorizableContract,
CanResetPasswordContract interfaces.

Those interfaces deals with `can` middleware. This is way you received that error message.

Answer (score 0):

This middleware is used by the `AuthorizesRequests` trait [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L74-L98).